# WCF service managed by a WPF application?

Tags: wpf, wcf, service

I am new to WCF and I have some difficulties understanding certain things...

I want to create a web service, so I have created a WCF application service that I will be  able to host via my IIS server, so far so good, right ?

But that service need some settings, like the SQL Server address where he have to get his data. And that's where I don't understand how I am supposed to create a WPF application that will control the service.

I know how to create a client application to consume the service, but how to create a WPF application that will be installed on the server, and when launched will retrieve the service and allow me to tell him parameters I want him to use.

If someone could give me the overall workflow, it will be greatly appreciate ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, there's a configuration file that goes with the web service (like the app.config file for applications). The file is called `web.config`. This is the place where you configure everything - from the service behavior to specific settings like connection strings etc.

Usually you do not have a configuration tool for a web service - you edit the `web.config` file and you're done.

**EDIT**
OK, if you really want such a program, there *are* ways to do that. I'd try the following:

The `web.config` file contains a section called `appSettings` for application settings. This section can be outsourced into a separate file. The line to include such a file would look like:

```
<appSettings file="mysettings.config"/>
```

The file itself would contain a normal `appSettings` section:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Info" value="myself" />
</appSettings>
```

Now you could have a normal application that reads the XML file `mysettings.config` and is able to write a changed version of the file (please note that you need appropriate rights to read/write the file).

While you shouldn't need to restart IIS or the WebService upon changes to the `web.config` file, I'm not sure about changes to the `mysettings.config` file - you might need to restart your WebService after modifying the file.

Another way would be to create functions in the service that allows a client to get/change settings and the service itself stores them somewhere.

Comment: Yes but I'd like to have a configuration application, because I am planing to have quite a few settings, so I'd like a nice way to manage them.

Comment: Added a suggestion to my answer.

Comment: I see, I just hope that the IIS server doesn't have to be restarted. Or may be I could directly edit the web.config file with my normal application. I was thinking of something like Corbian by exemple, you have the service always runing, and when you need to edit your backup settings you start the UI of Corbian Backup.